# Monodromy matrix : Why is there a non singular matrix $M$ such that $Y(t)=X(t)M$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $A(t)$ a $\mathcal M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ periodic matrix, i.e. there is $T$ such that $A(t+T)=A(t)$. We consider the ODE $$\dot x(t)=A(t)x(t).$$
Let $\mathrm X(t)$ the fundamental matrix, i.e. the solution of $$\dot{\mathrm X}(t)=A(t)\mathrm X(t),\quad \mathrm X(0)=I_n,\tag{1}$$
where $I_n$ is the identity matrix in $\mathcal M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$. Let $\mathrm Y(t)=\mathrm X(t+T)$. Then $$\dot {\mathrm Y}(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\mathrm X(t+T)=A(t+T)\mathrm X(t+T)=A(t)\mathrm X(t+T)=A(t)\mathrm Y(t).$$

Then it's written that since $(1)$ has exactly $n$ linear independent solution, there is a non-singular matrix $M$ such that $$\mathrm Y(t)=\mathrm X(t)M.$$

I don't understand this last argument. Could someone explain ? In what the fact that $(1)$ has $n$ linearly independent solution will implies the existence of such a matrix $M$ ? (by the why, why $(1)$ has only $n$ linearly solution ?)

Comment: $M = X(0)^{-1} X(T)$ then $X(t+T)-X(t)M$ is the unique solution of $z' = A z$ with initial condition $0$ thus $X(t+T)-X(t)M=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the fundamental matrix is regular at all points. Then $M=X(0)^{-1}X(T)=X(T)$ is well-defined and regular.

Now confirm that $Z(t)=X(t)M$ is also a solution of the matrix ODE, and that because of $Z(0)=M=X(T)=Y(0)$ you get $Z(t)=Y(t)$ everywhere.

Comment: What do you mean by regular ? Invertible ?

Comment: Yes, the opposite of singular, also having full rank. See Wronski-determinant, its differential equation and solution formula.